# Replacement macros for M_ASN1_D2I_

Tags: openssl

I am migrating OpenSSL to 1.1.1,
I am getting error for below macros:

```
M_ASN1_D2I_vars(a, X509_CRL *, X509_CRL_new)
M_ASN1_D2I_Init()
M_ASN1_D2I_start_sequence()
M_ASN1_D2I_get(ret->crl, d2i_X509_CRL_INFO)
M_ASN1_D2I_get(ret->sig_alg, d2i_X509_ALGOR)
M_ASN1_D2I_get(ret->signature, d2i_ASN1_BIT_STRING)
M_ASN1_D2I_Finish(a, X509_CRL_free, ASN1_F_X509_CRL_ADD0_REVOKED);
```

Can anyone help me to identify alternative macros/functions in openssl1.1.1 for this one?